# Watir Script called within a Watir Script

Tags: ruby, watir

is it possible to call a test script into a seperate test script?

eg. I create 10 test scripts and instead of copying them and harnessing, I want to just call them let's say by their filenames on a separate script.

Can anyone teach me how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is Ruby feature. Please read [Including Other Files](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html#S4).

In short:

```
load "filename.rb"
require "filename"
```

> The load method includes the named
>   Ruby source file every time the method
>   is executed, whereas require loads any
>   given file only once

Answer (score 2):

If you create your seperate test scripts using [WATIR Test Unit](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Test+Unit) you can combine the separate scripts as simply as,

```
require "test/unit"

require "001_workflow_selector"
require "002_pub_browser"
require "003_login"
```

Test Unit will handle the calling of each script you include within the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that runs another script that is not predefined.

```
def runRubyScript command
   scriptpath = 'C:/autotest/fitnesse/Scripts/'
   system('cmd.exe /c ruby #{scriptpath}' + command)
end
```

In general, I believe that Alastair's and Željko's answers are the best ways to do this, but this way would allow you to read in a script list from a file or stream without pre-definied knowledge of the files.

Dave